# AndroidManifest.xml <manifest> package attribute has no namespace

Tags: android, xml

From the O'Reilly book "Android Application Development " by Rick Rogers, John Lombardo, Zigurd Mednieks & Blake Meike, page 44:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.microjobsinc.mjandroid" android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">
```

The XML code above has the `package` attribute. However, in the rest of the XML, the remaining attributes all have a namespace.

Why do all of the attributes have a namespace except `package`?

Comment: Quoting JS: "Downvoters: please provide comments. – Jon Skeet May 8 at 9:25"

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be because the package attribute is the full Java package name for the application and so is a Java concept not something specific to Android. It does stick out as unusual though but it is the correct way according to http://d.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html